# SDL Window is transparent

Tags: c, sdl, graphical-programming

I'm learning SDL and tried to set up a window with a red background.
Followed this [code](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderClear) but got the result that is different from an expected one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
        SDL_Log(SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }

    SDL_Window* wnd = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 300, 300, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(wnd, 0, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255 , 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Delay(6000);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: a Transparent window]

Comment: SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0 , 255); try this to make it red

Comment: You are creating a window for use with OpenGL but using the SDL APIs to draw to it...

Answer (score 1):

Process the OS event queue via a `SDL_WaitEvent()`/`SDL_PollEvent()`/`SDL_PumpEvents()` loop instead of a big 'ole main-thread-blocking `SDL_Delay()`.